# How can I change KDE Meta+P options

Tags: display, kde, plasma

When I press `META+P`, I get the following options using KDE:

- Switch to external screen
- Switch to laptop screen
- Unify outputs
- Extend to left
- Extend to right

Is it possible to modify these settings, so it changes to a predefined setup?

EDIT: Or are there any programs that replace this functionality, for which I can set the keybind?

Comment: Shortcuts are configurable in KDE settings. Open settings and type "shortcuts" in search.

Comment: I'm aware that shortcuts are configurable, just haven't found a way to change the options in the menu that shows up when I press the shortcut.